# How can I convert JSON data to PList data in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json

I am querying an external service which is passing back JSON data. I'd like to format this data as a binary PList to send it out to clients. How can I do that conversion in Rails?  This is a complex data structure with arrays & hashes as well as strings & integers.

Based on the comment, I am trying this:

```
def friends_facebook
  @graph = Koala::Facebook::GraphAPI.new(current_user.facebook_token.token)
  render :plist => JSON.parse(@graph.get_connections("me", "friends").to_json)
end
```

Which results in the error (on the render line):

```
incompatible encoding regexp match (ASCII-8BIT regexp with UTF-8 string)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using http://plist.rubyforge.org/ and http://flori.github.com/json/ :

```
JSON.parse(input).to_plist
```

You might have to write your own `to_plist_node` method(s) for your data structure(s).

Comment: Thanks very much for the comment. I have revised my question to take into consideration your point. How would you suggest I continue?

Comment: `plist` only supports XML plist, it would not convert JSON to binary plist.